# Logging into a website automatically in Visual C#? (No WebBrowser)

Tags: c#, download

I am trying to log in to a website using Visual C# but I am not sure where to start. Eventually, I want to download a PDF File from the website but I must login to the website as it is password-restricted. The url is below:

https://sso.greatclips.com/authentication/login/login.aspx?ud=1&ApplicationCode=1&ReturnURL=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.salondata.com%2Fv2%2Fwa%2FloginPostBack

I am not sure if it is working. What are my options, and is the code even doing anything?

Here is my code so far. (Note: I do not want to browse the web in the Visual C# App, I want it done in the background)

```
    public static Setup setup = new Setup();
    private CookieContainer _jar = new CookieContainer();
    public static string password = setup.Password;
    public static string username = setup.UserName;
    private string _url = "https://sso.greatclips.com/authentication/login/login.aspx";
    private string _userAgent;
    public Salons()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void Salons_Load_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string responseData;
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(_url);

        webRequest.CookieContainer = _jar;
        webRequest.Method = "POST";
        webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        webRequest.UserAgent = _userAgent;

        string requestBody = String.Format(
            "client_id={0}&password={1}", username, password);

        using (StreamWriter requestWriter = new StreamWriter(webRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {

            requestWriter.Write(requestBody);
            lblStatus.Text = "Writing request ...";
            requestWriter.Close();

            using (HttpWebResponse res = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse())
            {
                using (StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream()))
                {

                    responseData = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
                    responseReader.Close();
                    lblStatus.Text = "Closing request ...";

                    if (res.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
                        throw new WebException("Logon failed", null, WebExceptionStatus.Success, res);
                    else
                        lblStatus.Text = "Successfully logged in!";
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

EDIT:

Request when I click on Sign In Button:

POST http://sso.greatclips.com/authentication/login/login.aspx?ud=1&ApplicationCode=1&ReturnURL=https%3a%2f%2fwww.salondata.com%2fv2%2fwa%2floginPostBack HTTP/1.1
Host: sso.greatclips.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:14.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/14.0.1
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
DNT: 1
Connection: keep-alive
X-MicrosoftAjax: Delta=true
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-cache
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8
Referer: http://sso.greatclips.com/authentication/login/login.aspx?ud=1&ApplicationCode=1&ReturnURL=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.salondata.com%2Fv2%2Fwa%2FloginPostBack
Content-Length: 1331
Cookie: stayloggedin=399238; ASP.NET_SessionId=g3tf01mqzgcdbhyoagfz1s55; .ADAuthCookie=2496474AAA6C67DC05253300439E06151F94E728769EA71FBFDB0CD832E772DBA6F5B5220EF7A5C7E79ED7B445EB7DF6C39B9A1E276277BDD3DC9DF2756294157D57C1B926F919F3A87BDE0CDBA8F43E0C8989357A24372DEA39B973A53F89F0EDEE1E2D3B391A785B1AB19FB704B420BD95A5C3505765D51FA865565686F3CF0F74AFD2C2E76146AB14F46BC2E4B21189B721C32DF3A6466631D0326ABB0D95087FF9E2
Pragma: no-cache

ctl00%24ScriptManager1=ctl00%24UpdatePanel1%7Cctl00%24cphMain%24loginMain%24LoginButton&_*EVENTTARGET=&*_EVENTARGUMENT=&_*VIEWSTATE=%2FwEPDwUKMjA3MDY5NDk2Ng9kFgJmD2QWBAIBD2QWBGYPZBYCZg9kFgICAQ8WAh4EVGV4dAUQUmVwb3J0aW5nIENlbnRlcmQCAg9kFgICAQ9kFgICAQ8WAh8ABRpzVGl0bGVCYWNrZ3JvdW5kPScjNUU3MUI2J2QCAw9kFgYCAw8PFgYeCEltYWdlVXJsBRppbWFnZXMvc3BlY3RydW1fYmFubmVyLmpwZx4NQWx0ZXJuYXRlVGV4dAUQUmVwb3J0aW5nIENlbnRlch4HVmlzaWJsZWdkZAIFD2QWAmYPZBYCAgEPDxYEHglCYWNrQ29sb3IJ%2FPz8%2Fx4EXyFTQgIIZBYCAgEPZBYCAgMPZBYCAgEPPCsACgEADxYCHghVc2VyTmFtZQUbc3VkZXNoLnNhcHJhQGdyZWF0Y2xpcHMubmV0ZBYCZg9kFgYCAQ8PFgIfAAUQUmVwb3J0aW5nIENlbnRlcmRkAgUPDxYCHwAFG3N1ZGVzaC5zYXByYUBncmVhdGNsaXBzLm5ldGRkAhkPDxYCHwAFGHdlYm1hc3RlckBncmVhdGNsaXBzLmNvbWRkAgkPDxYCHwAFEUNvcHlyaWdodCDCqSAyMDEyZGQYAQUeX19Db250cm9sc1JlcXVpcmVQb3N0QmFja0tleV9fFgEFJ2N0bDAwJGNwaE1haW4kbG9naW5NYWluJGNoa1N0YXlMb2dnZWRJbufuwcvYeS4gDjHhavP572TVdscK&*_EVENTVALIDATION=%2FwEWCQL%2B5bxcAr2ailYCkqyM%2BQ0CtvDI7gECpJCinAICzoverwUCjqr%2B%2FAoCocjV5gcCybrK0QNROj0%2BEho3liuMeskLfe3LtC8Zog%3D%3D&ctl00%24cphMain%24loginMain%24UserName=***&ctl00%24cphMain%24loginMain%24UserName_TextBoxWatermarkExtender_ClientState=&ctl00%24cphMain%24loginMain%24Password=***&ctl00%24cphMain%24loginMain%24chkStayLoggedIn=on&__ASYNCPOST=true&ctl00%24cphMain%24loginMain%24LoginButton=Sign%20In

Comment: There are a lot of wrong things with your code. First, client_id and password are not reffering to anything on the login page. Second, you are improperly checking if the user has logged in. As long as the response is normally returned from the page, the HTTPStatusCode would be OK. So, you must check it using something along the lines of `if (responseData.Contains("Hello User") || responseData.Contains("Logged In")) { //Logged In }`. I can't really test your code because I don't have an account there so it will always send me the source indicating that I am not logged in.

Answer (score 0):

Couple things which can help you

(a) this url also works without SSL (so you will not have a deal with check the right certificate, etc), and for now you can just try to do this work with url http://sso.greatclips.com/authentication/login/login.aspx?ud=1&ApplicationCode=1&ReturnURL=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.salondata.com%2Fv2%2Fwa%2FloginPostBack  (http instead of https)

(b) use [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) tool which allows you to logs the traffic between browser and web server. Just take a look on request which browser sends to server when you click on Sign In button and try to implement the same request in C# code.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am not sure how to implement the same request. I edited my original question to include the request and response.

Comment: Why you are trying to set the request body like this "client_id={0}&password={1}", from fiddler request you see that ctl00%24cphMain%24loginMain%24UserName contains login and ctl00%24cphMain%24loginMain%24Password contains password. Try to change your request in C# code to make it similar for request which you see in fiddler. Use the same names for header properties, etc.